# "SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost"

Tags: php, laravel

I get this

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
```

I dont undderstand why because I changed my DB name, username and password in my `.env` once I installed Laravel. It worked earlier when I migrated my tables!  I tried to clear the cache with `php artisan config:clear` still nothing. I saw other asking for similar problems but got the solution by changing their `.env`.

Comment: How do you run laravel?

Comment: Restart laravel setup

Comment: I mean restart your laravel project

Comment: If you are using `php artisan serve` and change your `.env` variables you need to restart laravel's server for changes to take effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that you have changed DB password and earlier it was working
So,If you have changed the `.env` then you need to restart your artisan server for make those changes in effect.

```
php artisan serve
```

Comment: Yep, restart the "serve" and it should work. thanks Bhavin

Answer (score 0):

Goto phpmyadmin > User Accounts and Update the privileges.

[image]

**Select the user and click on edit privileges, Check all and you're Done.**

Answer (score 0):

After changing .env file you need to stop the server and run it again (php artisan serve). Cause laravel gets the environment when it's initialized the server. If you don't restart, you will change the .env asking yourself why the changes aren't taking place!!